# Disable sound in application

Tags: android, audio

How can i disable my sound in android app. I use a checkbox and this is code

```
cbAudio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(isChecked){
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
    }else {
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
}
}
   });
```

but it does not work. may have other ways?

Comment: what is the result of it does not work ? is it gives an error ?

Comment: Don't use `setStreamMute`, just set the volume to 0. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html "This method should only be used by applications that replace the platform-wide management of audio settings or the main telephony application."

Comment: NetStarter, no there is no error, just nothing happends. the sound is not disabled.

Comment: Ken Wolf, something like this audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);